# Must I call *sql.Rows.Close() before *sql.Tx.Rollback() calling?

Tags: mysql, go

When I using `sql` package of golang, if I make a query within transaction, and encounter an error while calling `rows.Scan()`, which method should I call first after this point? `*sql.Tx.Rollback()` or `*sql.Rows.Close()`? Currently I call `*sql.Rows.Close()` before `*sql.Tx.Rollback()`, but I want to know, what will happen if I reverse this order?

```
tx, err := db.Begin()
if err != nil {
    ... // handle error
}


rows, err := tx.Query("sqlstmt")
if err != nil {
    ... // handle error
}


defer rows.Close() // can I use defer at this place, though it will be called after tx.Rollback()?


if err := rows.Scan(vars...); err != nil {
    if e := tx.Rollback(); e != nil {
        log(e)
        return e
    }
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/44812/

The code is here

It doesn't matter even if skip the `rows.Close()` within transaction

When the transaction has commit or rollback, the rows will be closed by transaction context.